# Where to test setters of entities?

Tags: hibernate, orm, junit, dao, defensive-programming

I am writing unit tests for a Spring web application that uses Hibernate for data persistence. I haven't developed the application. I wonder whether it is a good idea to write JUnit tests testing setters of entities to ensure that defensive programming was applied (that is to test that application won't try to insert invalid data into database, e.g: testing that age isn't negative).

On the other hand I see that @Size, @NotEmpty and similar annotations are already used with fields of entities.

This brings me to a question: What is the appropriate place/layer to put the guards for the interaction with database and is it necessary to write tests for entity setters?

Comment: It seems like you're calling entities DAOs. You'd better call them entities, because DAOs are not entities. DAOs are stateless objects used to access the database.

Comment: My bad. They are indeed entities and are placed in the entity package. I'll edit my question, but the core of the question remains the same